# How to repair candelabra?

Tags: metal, soldering, welding

I'm looking for advice on the best way to repair a candelabra made from either wrought iron or mild steel similar to the one in the photo below. It is made up of several parts either welded or soldered together. I don't have any gas or arc welding equipment but as the strength of the joins is not critical, would it be possible to solder them using a gas blowtorch and a tin-lead solder?

[image]

Comment: For something that might drop a burning candle if repair fails, I would try a local garage/welding shop and have it done right.  Will cost about the same as solder or glue.

Comment: I thought this was a DIY forum?

Comment: It is, but would you advise someone to do something that might burn down their house and/or kill someone?  Sometimes pointing someone to the best place is the best answer.  If you promise no one will ever use lighted candles, then solder or epoxy glue should work for a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that holding a candle is pretty critical. I'd get a Mapp gas torch and some small brazing rods and do it right.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it's only used for ornamental purposes. Would silver soldering be the way to go?

Comment: @jrcollins  Silver soldering would  work on mild steel or case iron.

Comment: It really only needs to be strong enough to hold it together. That's why I was thinking I could use a soft solder. I already have a propane blowtorch but that wouldn't be hot enough for silver soldering/brazing.

Comment: You can use propane and it will be hot enough for silver solder. It will just take longer than Mapp Gas to heat up the surface.

Comment: Is there much of a difference between the soldering rods vs soldering wire? Is it just that the rods are flux coated?

Comment: @jrcollins  Personally, I like the rods better. Yes, they have the flux which is nice but they are more rigid and easier to direct the flow.